# Qt C++ : read data from multiple slaves using Modbus RTU class (RS485)

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port, modbus, rs485

I tried reading values from 1 temperature sensor using Qt modbus class in the following way :

```
QModbusDataUnit(QModbusDataUnit::InputRegisters, /*startAddress*/ 1000, /*numberOfEntries*/ 1 );
```

Now what I want is reading values from different slaves ( different device ID's same port).

I tried pymodbus as its functions has device id argument (example : unit=0x03) :

```
result = client.read_input_registers(0x03E8 ,1, unit=0x03)
```

But I can't figure out how to do the same using Qt.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That's not so straightforward as you might think and QtModbus is not very well documented but I think you need to do it in the query using `serverAddress` as your slave ID:

```
QModbusReply *QModbusClient::sendReadRequest(const QModbusDataUnit &read, int serverAddress)
```

See [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmodbusclient.html#details) for some (not much) more detail.